# How to display decimal numbers with dot instead of comma in HTML Input tag type="number" in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, ecmascript-6

I would like to know how can I use `.` to separate decimals in a HTML Input tag *type="number"* instead of `,` using Google Chrome (Version 89.0.4389.82) MacOs Catalina.

So far from what I've tried *Firefox* is the only browser which splits decimal numbers with `.`

Does anyone faced this issue?
Any ideas how to fix it?

```html
<input type="number" value="1.5" step="0.1" min="0" />
```

Comment: in window, using google chrome, i am seeing . instead of  ','

Comment: It's based on your region. Take a look at this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqOe3.png

Comment: @GucciBananaKing99 do you know how can i set my _region_ ?

Comment: Normally it's based on the GPS

Answer (score 0):

Browser decimal separators differ according to the region. I think your issue is parsing the value for different regions( , and .)

Use [valueAsNumber](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110405/common-input-element-attributes.html#dom-input-valueasnumber) to extract the value

> **valueAsNumber** *(MDN Documentation)*
>
> double: Returns the value of the element, interpreted as one of the following, in order:
>
> - A time value
> - A number
> - NaN if conversion is impossible

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  const ageInput = document.querySelector('#age');
  console.log('Age:', ageInput.valueAsNumber);
  console.log('Type of Age:', typeof ageInput.valueAsNumber);
});
```

```html
<input id="age" type="number" value="1.5" step="0.1" min="0" pattern="[0-9]+([,\.][0-9]+)?" />
```

Also added pattern for sake of completeness.

Comment: thx for the answer :)  But as you can see the input field still showing the number separated by `,` and not by `.`  (Chrome MacOs)

Can I set the region somehow?